# Merged String Checker at codewars

Tags: java, string, algorithm

At a job interview, you are challenged to write an algorithm to check if a given string, s, can be formed from two other strings, part1 and part2.

The restriction is that the characters in part1 and part2 are in the same order as in s.

The interviewer gives you the following example and tells you to figure out the rest from the given test cases.

For example:

'codewars' is a merge from 'cdw' and 'oears':

See: https://www.codewars.com/kata/merged-string-checker/train/java

This is my java code,but couldn't pass all test.Excuse me, where is wrong?Thank you!

```
public static boolean isMerge(String s, String part1, String part2) {
    s = s.replace(" ","");
    part1 = part1.replace(" ","");
    part2 = part2.replace(" ","");

    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    char[] cp1 = part1.toCharArray();
    char[] cp2 = part2.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
        char is = s.charAt(i);
        if (index1 < cp1.length && cp1[index1] == is) {
            index1++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (index2 < cp2.length && cp2[index2] == is) {
            index2++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return s.length() == index1 + index2;
}
```

Comment: When you stepped through your code with a debugger, what did you discover?

Comment: Consider the line at `return false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if for example you have:

S = cdwzzzcdw

part1 = cdw

part2 = cdwzzz

What happens is that first you try to match the whole part1 with the beginning of S, and part won't be able to match the rest of the string. But if you have considered part2 first, the it would be properly done.

So, the bottom line is that you should consider all the possibilites. I assume a dyanmic programming approach would work. Here is a pseudocode in C++:

```
bool rec(idx1, idx2, idxS ){
    if(idx1 == part1.length && idx2 == part2.length){
        if(idxS == S.length) return true; //everything matched
        return false; //S has remaining

    }
    if(idxS == S.length){ //length part1 + part2 is more than S
        return false;
    }
    if(mark[idx1][idx2][idxS] == true) //computed before
        return dp[idx1][idx2][idxS];

    mark[idx1][idx2][idxS] = true;
    dp[idx1][idx2][idxS] = false;

    if(idx1 < part1.length && part1[idx1] == S[idxS]){
        if(rec(idx1 + 1, idx2, idxS + 1) == true) {
            dp[idx1][idx2][idxS] = true;
        }
    }
    if(idx2 < part2.length && part2[idx2] == S[idxS]){
        if(rec(idx1, idx2 + 1, idxS + 1) == true){
            dp[idx1][idx2][idxS] = true;
        }
    }
    return dp[idx1][idx2][idxS];
}
```